# Using WINAPI ReadConsole

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, keyboard-input

I am trying to use the WINAPI `ReadConsole()` to wait for any keypress at the end of my Win32 console application.

```
CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL tControl;
char pStr[65536];
DWORD dwBufLen = 1;
DWORD dwCtl;

tControl_c.nLength = sizeof( CONSOLE_READCONSOLE_CONTROL );
tControl_c.nInitialChars = 0;
tControl_c.dwControlKeyState = 0;
tControl_c.dwCtrlWakeupMask = NULL;

pBuf[0] = 0x00;

do
{
   ReadConsole( hConsole_c, pStr, (*pBufLen) * sizeof(TCHAR), pBufLen, &tControl );
}
while ( pStr[0] == 0x00 );
```

The code executes without throwing an exception.  However, when the `ReadConsole()` function executes the error code `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (0x06) is flagged.  I have verified `hConsole_c` to be a valid handle.  Does anyone have any insight as to what I am doing wrongly?  I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me.  The only way I could get it to fail with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE was to pass it the STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE instead of the STD_INPUT_HANDLE.  Are you sure hConsole_c is the input handle?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to wait for keypress at the end of your console app
why dont you try `System("Pause");` ?

Comment: Yes,  but I went to all the trouble of writing a wrapper class for the WINAPI Console functions. I'd like to use it. Do you have any suggestions for getting the above code to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your method of waiting for a keystroke is very over-complex. Using single C function calls, there are a couple of ways you can do this:

- `getch();` (or the ISO C++ conformant name, `_getch`), which is platform independent;
- `system("pause");`, which is Windows-specific.

Comment: Yes, I have a working function that uses the ISO calls, but I went to all the trouble of writing a wrapper class for the WINAPI Console functions.  I'd like to use it.  Do you have any suggestions for getting the above code to work?